# Can I write the Taylor series of some function $f(x)$ around $x=1$ as: $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n (x-1)^{2n-1}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

Can I write the Taylor series of some function $f(x)$ around $x=1$ as:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n (x-1)^{2n-1}.$$

Thnx.

Comment: Sure. Why not?${}$

Comment: If the even derivatives of $f$ at $1$ are all zero ($f^{(2n)}(1)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$), then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As given, it means that

$$a_k=\begin{cases}0,&k\;\text{is even}\\{}\\a_{2n-1},& k=2n-1\;\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$